# How to do Multiple URL Mapping (aliases) in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

**In specific**

I want to do Multiple URL Mapping (in other words aliases) in spring boot

**In Detail**

In my spring boot application
**Customer Controller** class has mapped primarily to the `/customer` URL as below I want to create easily changeable aliases

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/customer")
public class CustomerController{
```

In my normal spring application where I do the mapping in the XML, I can do the URL mapping as below.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
   <property name="mappings">
    <props>
       <prop key="/customer.htm">customerController</prop>
       <prop key="/tester.htm">customerController</prop>
     </props>
   </property>
</bean>

<bean id="customerController" 
    class="com. ... .controller.CustomerController" />
```

Spring boot, property file configurations are helpful in most of the time as the autoconfig is working under the roof.

1. Is there any way I can do the same using the property files.
2. What is the best practice to follow when doing a URL mapping in spring boot which I can change easily after the compilation.

*I tired alot to find this. But at the end ended up in the SO community help. Please help me on this.*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to drive mapping out of a prop file, then you can do it as below

In you application.properties, add the key value pair

```
url.mapping : /test/sample
```

On the controller you can the do the following:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = { "${url.mapping}" })
public class CustomerController{
```

Instead of providing in prop file, if you provide the `url.mapping` as a `jvm arg`, then you don't have to recompile if you change the value, just restart (which i hope you can do, have not tried it myself) should do the trick.

For multiple mappings, you will have to add one per mapping and map that in controller like below.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = { "${url.mapping}","${url.mapping.two}" })
public class CustomerController{
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: @FarajFarook. Accepting helps others and me :)

Comment: Is it possible to configure this with multiple mappings? For example: url.mappings: <<list of all mappings>>

Answer (score 31):

Take a look at [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) example.

The best way to map url is to do it in the controller with annotations.

Basically:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

}
```

IMHO
The best practice is to use one mapping for the controller and one for every method:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/Hello")
    public class HelloController {

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String index() {
            return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/otherMapping")
        public String otherMapping() {
            return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
        }
    }
```

That way urls will look like: `localhost:8080/Hello` and `localhost:8080/Hello/otherMapping`

**Edit:**

For multiple mappings you can use:

```
@RequestMapping({ "/home", "/contact" })
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I updated my question. I need to do multiple URL mappings like aliases. I would prefer to change the alias mapping without recompile.

Comment: @FarajFarook See update. I can't help for the "no compilation" part.

Comment: Thank you Evgeni. Your help is highly appreciate. I up-voted your answer. But I will wait for few more comments on this to find if there is any way to do this without recompiling :)

Comment: The new annotations also work: `@GetMapping({"/path1"', "path2"})`